# Word for distanced person with air of superiority

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a good adjective to describe someone who knows they're above others, and while not boastful, they are not forthcoming or approachable? I'm not trying to describe someone who is antisocial or outright unkind.

For example, think of a popular girl in high-school who knows she gets a lot of attention. She holds this fact above everyone else and thus only stays to her social group of similar girls, mostly ignoring everyone else.

> I could never muster the courage to approach the ___ girl who sat in
>   front of me in Biology class.

This word probably has a negative connotation, but not synonymous with malicious or reclusive.

Comment: To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Comment: There is a sample sentence.

Comment: I added an example after Cascabel's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on your description, my first thought was [haughty](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/haughty) or one of its synonyms:

> Arrogantly superior and disdainful. (Oxford Dictionaries)

Another that I like, which is less pejorative, is [lofty](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/lofty):

> 2: very high and good : deserving to be admired.
>   3 : showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people. 
>   (Merriam-Webster *Learner's Dictionary*)

However, in the context of your sample sentence, there is one clearly appropriate word:

> I could never muster the courage to approach the **cool** girl who sat in front of me in Biology class.

[***Cool***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cool) is a word with a lot of nuances of meaning, many of which work in your context:

> 2. Showing no friendliness towards a person or enthusiasm for an idea or project.
>
>    - 2.1 Free from excitement, anxiety, or excessive emotion.
>    - 2.2 (*of jazz*) restrained and relaxed.
> 3. *informal* Fashionably attractive or impressive.
>
>    - 3.1 Excellent.
>        (Oxford Dictionaries)

At least in the US, a student who is attractive and popular and slightly "above" the regular student body, but without being actively boastful or cruel, is almost the definition of "cool".

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a word that conveys an air of superiority. Consider *aloof*. As the example accompanying the following definition shows, being aloof doesn't necessarily mean being unkind or mean.

> **aloof** *adjective*
>   1 Not friendly or forthcoming; cool and distant.
>   ‘they were courteous but faintly aloof’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aloof)

Note, though, that the word isn't normally used to describe a noun, as you're seeking with the phrase *aloof girl*. It describes the person's behaviour - e.g. *she was aloof* or *she stayed aloof*.

Answer (score 0):

> **[snobbish:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snobbish)** (M-W)
>
> **having or showing the attitude of people who think they are better than other people.**
>
> **of or relating to people who are snobs.**

"I could never muster the courage to approach the ***snobbish*** girl who sat in front of me in Biology class."

> (**[Snob](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snob)**:  :  one who blatantly imitates, fawningly admires, or
>   vulgarly seeks association with those regarded as social superiors
>
> one who tends to rebuff, avoid, or ignore those regarded as
>   inferior.   one who has an offensive air of superiority in matters of
>   knowledge or taste).